# How to create multi dimension arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

When user submits form the data is stored in array & serialized & stored in the database, when user again submit another form then that data is stored in array & previous serialized array is fetched from database & is unserialized.

Now i want both these array to be multi dimensional, here is what I've tried

```
$post = array();
$post[] = $co_name = test_input($_POST['co_name1']);
```

this array is fetched from database
    $db = unserialize($db);

```
$db[] = $post;
print_r($db);
```

After Printing this is what i get

```
   Array
(
    [0] => company_name
            [1] => country
            [2] => city
            [3] => state
            [4] => pincode
            [5] => 2008
            [6] => 01
            [7] => 2008
            [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => company_name
            [1] => country
            [2] => city
            [3] => state
            [4] => pincode
            [5] => 2008
            [6] => 01
            [7] => 2008
        )

)
```

Now my problem is second array is assigned to 8, how to perfectly create multi dimension array

My desired output is my array should like this

```
array(
    0=>array(
        0=>company_name
        1=>country
    ),
    1=>array(
        0=>company_name
        1=>location
    )
)
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @RobbieAverill check the edited post

Comment: you are doing `$post = array(); $post[] = $co_name = test_input($_POST['co_name1']);` I believe you should do `$post[0] = array(); $post[1] = $co_name = test_input($_POST['co_name1']);` because first you create a copy of the first array and then push the second at the last position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you a numerically indexed array with your POST data as one value and DB data as another value of a new array. If you `var_dump` / `print_r()` this, the output will look similar to your desired output:

`$newArray = array($post, $db);`

However; Your desired output shows a reduced number of keys for each result:

- company_name
- country

...(or did you only write these to make it easier to read?)

If you *do* want just those two keys, consider using PHP's `array_filter` function which takes your combined array (above: `$newArray`) and a callback function as arguments. This allows you to manipulate any of the keys and values of the input array, to make the returned array look exactly as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the info with the correct array number example

```
$post = array();
$post[0] = $co_name = test_input($_POST['co_name1']); 
$post[1] = $co_name = test_input($_POST['co_name1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get an answer without more clarification. This problem is likely due to faulty serialization. 
How are you getting your data out of the db? 
What does the data in the db look like?

Comment: there is no fault this is what i got into database a:8:{i:0;s:7:"company";i:1;s:8:"location";i:2;s:4:"city";i:3;s:3:"ceo";i:4;s:2:"01";i:5;s:4:"2008";i:6
;s:2:"01";i:7;s:4:"2008";}